# Finding out through SQL or OLEDB which of an Access tables' columns is autoincremented?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I need to find all the multiple or non-autoincremented primary keys, make them normal keys, and make the primary key an autoincrement column. But I need to check if there is already an autoincrement column, so I make that one a primary key, in case if it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this Microsoft article on [How To Retrieve Column Schema by Using the DataReader GetSchemaTable Method and Visual C# .NET](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/310107/en-us) I have written a little code for you to pick the field with the auto increment set to `True`,

```
  OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
  DataTable schemaTable;
  OleDbDataReader myReader;

  //Open a connection to the SQL Server Northwind database.
  cn.ConnectionString = "...";
  cn.Open();

  //Retrieve records from the Employees table into a DataReader.
  cmd.Connection = cn;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
  myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

  //Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
  schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

  var myAutoIncrements = schemaTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(
              myField => myField["IsAutoIncrement"].ToString() == "True");

  foreach (var myAutoInc in myAutoIncrements)
  {
      Console.WriteLine((myAutoInc[0]));
  }

  Console.ReadLine();

  //Always close the DataReader and connection.
  myReader.Close();
  cn.Close();
```

You can simply paste this on you app or even a new console app and see the results of shown Fields with the `IsAutoIncrement` set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

OleDbReader has a GetSchemaTable method. You can call that with a basic select to each table, then loop through the returned columns and check for IsAutoIncrement.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx